# Dictionary of lists to Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, cartesian-product

I have a dictionary of lists, like `{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [5, 6, 7, 8]}`. There may by more than two key/value pairs in the actual data.  I want to display an *exhaustive* list of dictionaries, one per line, where each dictionary has the same keys, and each value is an element chosen from the corresponding original list.

So for this input, the result would look like

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 5}
{'a': 1, 'b': 6}
...
{'a': 3, 'b': 8}
```

with a total of 3 * 4 = 12 lines of output.

I can do this for hard-coded key names:

```
for a, b in itertools.product(*p.itervalues()):
    print({'a':a, 'b':b})
```

However, for the real data, I don't necessarily know the key names in advance, and there may be an unknown number of key-value pairs.

How can I fix the code so that it produces the desired dicts from the `itertools.product`, regardless of the keys?

Comment: Can you show an example with three keys in the dictionary?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of unpacking the `product` results into separate variables, just `zip` them with the original keys:

```
from itertools import product

for i in product(*p.values()):
    print(dict(zip(p, i)))
```

Comment: I actually have a doubt about this. Is the 'order' going to be the same for both `p.values` and `p.keys`?

Comment: I was actually going to answer my own question with that solution but I was unsure on the order of p.keys.  I somehow have the feeling that it's not reliable!

Comment: Checkout `__iter__()` in ParameterGrid https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.14.X/sklearn/grid_search.py.  Exactly what I want.

Comment: You can zip `p` with `i` directly and save the time spent on repeatedly creating the list of keys.

Comment: Damn, the Python is just too powerful. I spent half an hour working out a recursive solution due to my lack of practice with the itertools.